# Is there any way to limit amount of repeated items in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, javascript-objects

Is there any way by which I can limit repeated number of items in AngularJS? Like in contact list I need to enter same name and contact number but only 2 times and when I tried to enter 3rd time it shows me some alert that you have already entered contact details. How can I achieve this task by using AngularJS or JavaScript?

**My code is**

```html
<md-list-item ng-show="showContactList" ng-repeat="numbers in contactList track by $index" >
    <i ng-show="numbers.type == 'test'">textsms</i>
    <i ng-show="numbers.type == 'CELL' || numbers.type == 'EXT'">phone</i>
    <img ng-show="numbers.type == 'PAGER'" src="pager.png" width="26">
    <div class="md-list-item-text" ng-class="{'md-offset': phone.options.offset }">
          <h3>{{ numbers.type }}</h3>
          <p>{{ numbers.value }}</p>
    </div>
    <i ng-click="arrayText.push(numbers);">add</i>
</md-list-item>
```

On above code I'm able to add N number to contact name and number.

Comment: Where is the alert ? Where is the code detecting the duplicates ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and apologies for ambiguity. Alert and detecting duplicate values is not yet given. Right now I can enter only repeated items in the list.

Comment: You have to create a function to insert record, where you can check if data is already inserted.

Comment: I have one contact card in which I need only 2 names and 2 contacts. Right now I'm able to add N numbers of name and contact. If i limit to ng-repeat it will limit to list items. but I need to limit if name is inserted twice then it wont allow and show alert.

Comment: The title of the question is misleading. Your question is not related to `ng-repeat`

Comment: My question was correct and  you can see the answer posted by @ManojLodhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
  <i class="material-icons md-avatar-icon add-rm-icon margin-right" ng-click="insertRecord(numbers);">add</i>
```

Controller

```
  var existed = 0;
  $scope.insertRecord = function(numbers){
     var name = numbers.type;
     angular.forEach($scope.arrayText, function(value, key) {
     var arr = Object.values(value);
     if(arr.indexOf(name) !== -1 ) {
            existed++;
            console.info(existed);
      }
    });
    if(existed >= 2){
      console.info('already exist')
      existed = 0;
    }else{
      $scope.arrayText.push(numbers);
      existed = 0;
    }

  }
```

In `var name` variable you can put your property which you want to check for 2 time insertion.

Comment: I implemented this code and found that when i click on add icon, at a time 2 values get added. i.e if i add on name then 2 time name. if I add on contact then 2 times contact get added in the list.

Comment: @Sam I am not sure but i think you did not put your curly braces correctly, can you please check once ?

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is working for me. Thanks  a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit display items in ng-repeat by below code.

In HTML Template Binding

```
 {{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

In controller

```
  $filter('limitTo')(input, limit, begin)
```

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo for more detail.

**for limit item in insertion create function**

```
<i class="material-icons md-avatar-icon add-rm-icon margin-right" ng-click="pushFunction(numbers);">add</i>
```

in controller

```
$scope.pushFunction = funcation(numbers){
    // check number exist 
    $scope.existedNumbers = $scope.arratext.filter(function (objArray) {
       return (objArray == numbers);
    });
    if($scope.existedNumbers && $scope.existedNumbers.length<2)
      $scope.arrayText.push(numbers);
   else
      // show alert
};
```

Comment: he has to limit repeated items,not the loop :(

Comment: Exactly. I need to limit repeated items

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya Where did you check for same data insertion ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me implement then will get back to you.